# Issue updating and deploying sample data

Tags: magento2, installation, sample-data

I'm currently trying to complete the sample data installation but when i run the command.

```
php magento2/bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I keep getting the following errors in the terminal i'll paste it up to where it's displaying the error.

```
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
Module 'Magento_Captcha':
Module 'Magento_Reports':
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
Module 'Magento_Review':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData':



  [ReflectionException]                                                        
  Class Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media d  
  oes not exist                                                                






  [ReflectionException]                                                        
  Class Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media d  
  oes not exist
```

So i investigated further and in the error logs i found the following.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:1531:"Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_CatalogSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_BundleSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_DownloadableSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_ConfigurableSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_ThemeSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_ProductLinksSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_ReviewSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_SwatchesSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_GroupedProductSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_TaxSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CmsSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_SalesRuleSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_SalesSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_WidgetSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_WishlistSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0";i:1;s:2789:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#14 {main}";s:3:"url";s:10:"/magento2/";s:11:"script_name";s:19:"/magento2/index.php";}
```

So i ran the command

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And i'm getting the same error in the terminal that i posted above i'm not too sure that to do from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Magento form git repo than you need install sample data from repo too.

Please see documentation [how to deploy from repo](https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data#deploy-sample-data-from-github-repository)

Comment: So i've done this but i can't seem to link the sample data to my magenta install. I'm using MAMP btw and this is the command i'm running. php -f magento-sample-data/dev/tools/build-sample-data.php -- --ce-source="Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magneto2" It's saying it can't find the folder

Comment: Try run command from sample data root folder

Comment: Also you need  `/` before Application:  --ce-source="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magneto2"